# Authenticate my account evernote API

Tags: python, api, oauth, evernote

I'm trying to create a script to get some data and then create a note with them in evernote. 
Following the following example I can make a note, put in "dev", not in my own Evernote account. 
Example: http://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/python.php

I have a "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret", and I'm looking at this another example with doubts about what would be my "Callback URL". 
Example:https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python#usage

In summary, my question is: 
How to authenticate the script in my personal Evernote account as a customer for example.

Thank you in advance, and sorry if my question was not clear ...

Comment: Have you tried supplying no callback at all?

Comment: @ToonAlfrink I think not. I'm new, and I think my biggest doubt is: What is my Callback URL, how to get or create one.

Comment: Try setting your callback url as `""` and see what happens.

Comment: @ToonAlfrink, Thanks for the tip and disposition to help.

When you try the following:
client.get_authorize_url(request_token)

I get the following error:
KeyError: 'oauth_token'

Comment: Recalling that informed callback url as an empty string ""

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do OAuth, currently Evernote requires a callback URL. If you only want to access your own account, you can use a [developer token](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php#devtoken). You may find [this sample](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/blob/master/sample/client/EDAMTest.py) useful.

Comment: Following the example of (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python#usage)
I get the following error: NameError: name 'request' is not defined 

Up to this point "client.get_authorize_url (request_token)" everything is fine, get a dictionary which has its variable passed to the following values​​: 

client.get_access_token access_token = (
     request_token ['oauth_token'], 
     request_token ['oauth_token_secret'] 
     request.GET.get ('oauth_verifier','') 
) 

However, the error mentioned at the beginning occurs. How to define "request"? It's some "import" that is absent in my code?

Comment: Did you install `oauth2`?

Comment: No, not installed. After installing simply import to no longer receive the error "request"?